# Insert random picture in my GitHub README

Tags: r, git, github, markdown

I have a GitHub repo which is an R data package containing biological information on thousands of species. As part of the repo, I happen to have a little over 1k+ images of these species.

I thought it would be cool to have a different picture (a different from a particular folder) be displayed each time a user visited the site.

Is there any way to achieve that? If not, is there a semi-manual way to update the file selected without committing any changes?

Comment: I don't think this is possible using only github markdown.  You could put one of the images into the associated github wiki, and then link to that.  That way you could replace the image without pushing commits to the main repo by just changing it in the wiki. For a more complex solution, you could host the images somewhere else, with a script that returns a random one when someone hits the given link.

Comment: I like the idea of maybe using the wiki. Is there a way to get the image wiki to keep changing by itself? I have no idea how websites get new images to pop up etc.

Comment: I don't know a way to do it automatically with the wiki. II was suggesting it as an easy way to do manual edits. If you want to return different images you'd need a script that responds to web requests at the give url by running some logic and then returning a different url.  I don't think github wiki support running scripts, only static pages.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a semi-manual way to update the file selected without committing any changes?

Create an another repo(For example `images`). Then, write the image link to README.md in your R data repo, like this.

`![RandomImage][https://raw.githubusercontent.com/(YOUR-USERNAME)/images/master/random_image.png]`

If you want to update the random image, Update `random_image.png` in the `images` repo. There is no changes in your README.md file.

Comment: So then I have to store all the images on the other repo? And if the images are an integral part of the primary repo, then I have to maintain 2 copies or use submodules. Hmm. I can think about it, but that might just be a whole other pain to deal with.